# Can't download apps

Tags: ios, itunes, iphone

I tried to download an app, I tapped 
Get then install and a loading circle came up then I said Get again. I tried to sign out and into the App Store but it wouldn't let me sign back in.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a restart, this can be accomplished by holding the power button and home button together until the iPhone turns off and the Apple logo appears. This won't alter any of your data nor change any settings, but restarting it can solve problems like the one you have.